# All subsets of a set in Alloy

Tags: alloy

I am am struggling how to define a state change where one event can be posted per step but multiple removed. I have this model:

```
open util/ordering[State]
sig Event {}
sig State {
   queue : set Event
}

pred State.post( next' : State, event : Event ) {
  next'.queue = this.queue + event 
}

pred State.deliver( next' : State ) {   
   next'.queue = this.queue - this.queue // STRUGGLE!
}

fact traces {
   no first.queue
   all s : State - last, next : s.next {
      some e : Event | s.post[next,e] or s.deliver[next]
   }
}
```

However, I want to model that in the deliver step I deliver *some* events by removing them. In the code I deliver all but how do I code it that it will actually try any subset of `this.queue`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the struggle come from the fact you try to write this predicate as an assignment.

The solution becomes clear when adopting a more declarative view on the problem. It is simply needed to enforce that the new queue  be a proper subset of the previous queue:

```
pred State.deliver( next' : State ) {   
     next'.queue in this.queue and next'.queue != this.queue 
}
```

Comment: yes, I have hard time thinking not procedural although I do understand = is not an assignment :-) Thanks.